# THE 2MB per process is that exact or will it change

Tags: source, protocol

I have a technical question on the MB per process.  2MB is always quoted. Is is exactly 2MB or slightly less?  Is this a changing parameter that will change in the future?

Comment: Can you clarify further what it is you are talking about? 2MB of what per what process?